# Finding containing polygon for point with voronoi in D3js

Tags: d3.js, k-means

I'm trying to efficiently compute k-means using d3.js; I can create voronoi polygons for the current means, but how can I query which voronoi polygon each data point is contained within?

I've resorted to calculating the distance to each proposed mean:

```
// For each point calculate the nearest mean
// TODO partition the observations according to the Voronoi diagram generated by the means
for (var i = 0; i < xdata.length; i++) {
    var nearestDistance = 9999999999;

    for (var j = 0; j < k; j++) {
        var distance = Math.pow( xdata[i] - x_means[j], 2) + Math.pow( ydata[i] - y_means[j], 2);
        if(distance < nearestDistance){
            nearestDistance = distance;
            cdata[i] = j;
        }
    }
}
```

I have a minimum working example here:
http://bl.ocks.org/hardbyte/ded34566f6fb704264b4

Comment: You would need to have a separate map that tells you that, i.e. in a preprocessing step get the voronoi for each point and store that.

Comment: Do you mean store the voronoi for all the data points and the compute the intersection of each data points' polygon with each mean's polygon?

Comment: Well when you call the voronoi function, it returns the assignment of points to polygons. All you should need to do is save that and use it as a lookup table.